# All inbuilt functions when window.print();

Tags: javascript, printing, window

When use `window.print();` 
there are other function like

```
window.onprint ,
window.onafterprint,
window.onbeforeprint
```

How can I know all the other inbuilt functions ?

Comment: A quick search on Google would have lead to [documentation like this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window).

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know window.onprint(?), but you can always look through mdn web docs. Like for print - [window.print](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print).